# Best practice for cycling items through an array

Tags: c#, .net, json, uwp

I have a few ways of doing this but I'm not sure they're best practice, I just wanted to get your thoughts on the concept before I proceed.

Basically, I have a JSON array

```
 "new-samples": [ "Sample5", "Sample4", "Sample3", "Sample2", "Sample1" ]
```

The Sample is 5 items long, however if I wanted to add an item, I don't want the array to go to 6 items long, I want it to cycle, like so --

Add 1 Item:

```
 "new-samples": [ "Sample6", "Sample5", "Sample4", "Sample3", "Sample2" ]
```

Add 2 Items

```
"new-samples": [ "Sample7", "Sample6", "Sample5", "Sample4", "Sample3" ]
```

So what I'm doing currently is deserializing, deleting the last item, setting all the previous items to increase by 1, which leaves [0] empty to add my new sample into it. I'd either do that or create a new array, add in my new item at [0] and then take items [1][2][3][4] from the old array and stick it in the new one.

This is my example code as people have asked for it: Untested as well

```
JObject lpl = JObject.Parse(lpljson);
JArray jarray = (JArray)lpl["new-samples"];
List<string> nlpl = new List<string>();
nlpl.Add(AppNameBox.Text);
foreach (var item in jarray)
{
   nlpl.Add(item.ToString());
}

nlpl.RemoveAt(5);
jarray.RemoveAll();
foreach (var item in nlpl)
{
   jarray.Add(item);
}
```

Both seems a tad ugly, is there a faster or cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Post your complete working solution on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask there how to improve it.

Comment: We'll need to see how you're deserializing the data, at the very least. The type of structure you're using (`Array`, `List<T>`, `JArray`, etc.) will determine what advice to give. Note that pretty much all structures have a method for inserting an element at a particular index...

Comment: You can use ArrayList for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @sinatr check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is a [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

> Represents a first-in, first-out collection of objects.
>
> This class implements a queue as a circular array. Objects stored in a
>   Queue are inserted at one end and removed from the other.

Comment: Nice one, this is exactly what I was looking for. Nice and clean! Would never have guessed to look for 'Queue' in my search queries!

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer stated, a cycling [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) can make sense in this case, though a [Linked List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1) can also be efficient if you need to cycle either way. For very large collections with multiple simultaneous cycles (e.g. the academic array cycling exercise), one can also go for [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy), pay some allocation price and skip iterations altogether.

There are many ways of achieving this and the most *efficient* algorithm depends on the exact use case and language.

As this post is tagged C#, here is a sample extension method for the Queue that will do cycling for you. Assuming one only enqueues via this method, it's max O(n*2) where N is the number of items to add, plus some time to copy the underlying array whenever capacity needs to increase (Queue is implemented as a circular array). It's *good enough* for item-by-item shifts where the total capacity is known upfront, so you don't get the array adjustment hit. However, for use cases with unknown capacity and unknown shift count, far more efficient approaches can be taken.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Enqueues the given object.
        /// If the new queue size would be greater than <paramref name="capacity"/> then
        /// this method makes room for the new item by dequeueing until there is a spot.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to enqueue.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="queue">The queue to apply this extension on.</param>
        /// <param name="item">The object to enqueue.</param>
        /// <param name="capacity">
        /// The maximum queue capacity to enforce.
        /// If the new queue size would be greater than this value then items are dequeued until there is space for the new item.
        /// This value must greater than zero.
        /// </param>
        public static void Enqueue<T>(this Queue<T> queue, T item, int capacity)
        {
            if (queue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queue));
            if (capacity < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(capacity), capacity, $"Capacity is {capacity} but must be greater than zero.");

            // make room for the new item
            while (queue.Count > capacity - 1)
            {
                queue.Dequeue();
            }

            // enqueue the new item
            queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
```

The above said, the main blocker to efficiency there appears to be the full deserializing and re-serializing to JSON. What is the reason that needs to happen?